# Run a specific plugin before running tests in maven

Tags: maven

I have a requirement, where i need to execute a plugin before running unit tests or system tests. Is there any way i can make sure that my plugin executes before mvn test

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Maven build lifecycle runs in [phases](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html). Your plugin can be configure to run in a specific phase.

So you can configure it to run in compile phase or in test phase (just declare it before the maven-surefire-plugin for test phase)

Example of configuring plugin [phase](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html):

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```